# How can I get a shortcut to "Phone Dialer" in XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, voip

I have found the installed phone dialer in Windows XP Pro.

But the only way I have found to access it is through the `Run` Command.

How can I assign a shortcut to this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Phone Dialer is exactly, but if it's just an exe you can create a shortcut to it by right clicking on the file and selecting "Send to" and then Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

The executable should be in the `C:\Program Files\Windows NT` folder. Drag a shortcut to it to your desktop and\or start menu.